# Getting an error when trying to insert server ID into an sqlite database

Tags: python, sqlite, discord.py

I am trying to use an SQLite db to store punushment and warning history, and I am getting an error, below is the code:

```
@client.command()
@has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def warn(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason):
    db = sqlite3.connect('punishments.sqlite')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(f'''
    INSERT INTO {ctx.message.guild.id}\n
    VALUES({member.id}, {ctx.message.author.id}, {reason}, 'warning');
    ''')
    db.commit()
    cursor.close()
    db.close()
    await ctx.channel.send(f':white_check_mark: {member.mention} has been warned | {reason}')
    await member.send(f'You were warned for {reason}.')
```

and this is the error:

```
Ignoring exception in command warn:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 83, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:/Users/myname/guardian/bot.py", line 127, in warn
    cursor.execute(f'''
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "serverid": syntax error

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 892, in invoke        
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 797, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 92, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: OperationalError: near "serverid": syntax error
```

I have redcated the ID of the server as well as my name.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know if it's the problem, but the `'\n'` character is not required inside a triple quoted string.

Comment: You shouldn't use f-strings for generating sql commands. It makes your code vulnerable to SQL Injection.